Disable Click in Apex-Charts blazor
I’m building an application using .NET 8 and Blazor WASM. I’m utilizing Blazor Apex-Charts for charts and graphs. I’ve created a component that contains a chart and accepts a parameter for chart definition. This component is used multiple times (4-5 times) on a page to display multiple charts.
I want to implement a feature where clicking on a chart opens it in fullscreen. However, I'm encountering an issue: when I hover over the component, the chart’s click event gets triggered inadvertently. I need to disable all click events within the chart component and only enable clicks where the component is actually used on the page.
How can I achieve this?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
